# Is there a way to show menu bar when frame: false in Electron js?

Tags: javascript, electron, menubar, titlebar

I am trying to add custom title bar in Electron js for Windows. So to hide the default title bar I wrote:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false
});
```

But the above code hides the menu bar too. I want only the default title bar gone, without effecting the menu bar. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Electron's `frame` option to `false` creates a [frameless window](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#create-frameless-windows).

A frameless window does not have a title bar or menu. This is known as having no [chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Chrome).

From here you can build your own custom title bar with minimise, restore, maximise and close button functionality. If your application is being designed to work on different Operating Systems then you may wish to replicate button position, shapes and functionality.

Unfortunately, a side effect of using a frameless window is that you do lose your native menu. Again, this can be re-created using HTML, CSS and JS. That said, it will require a bit of work if you again wish to mimic more than one particular Operating System and be true to its design.

Alternatively, you can run with the one style of title bar and menu design across all Operating Systems. The choice is yours as a designer.

In summary, whilst it is possible to implement all of the above, it can be time consuming to set it up correctly. As a result, you really do need to weigh up if a custom title bar is worth the effort required to implement.

Comment: do you know of any blogs or good resources to achieve this custom menu bar?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Sorry. If the menu bar is only 1 level deep then it should be relatively easy to code. More than one level deep leads to the requirement of expansion arrows + hover and keyboard functionality that need to be resolved. If your custom menu requires icons or checkboxes, then CSS spacing using flexbox will also be in the mix. If you application is going to be cross platform compatible, then placing an OS titled CSS class in the HTML body tag is the way to go. That way, the HTML code can be the same and only the CSS code will make the UI look OS specific.